# How to create or import an Azure API Connection (Microsoft.Web) using Terraform?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform

My requirement is to create a Logic App that will receive some inputs from other resources like Azure Data Factory and send out an email. I created this setup using the Azure portal and Logic app designer. When I added a `Send an Email (V2)` I was asked for an Office 365 account login and everything works as expected.

Now I'm trying to achieve all of this through Terraform. I can import the existing Logic app workflow to an AzureRM resource `azurerm_logic_app_workflow` but that doesn't import the API connection. I'm unsure on how to import the existing API connection into Terraform (or even to create a new API connection in Terraform).

Please advise.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_connection Unfortunately, it does seem to be capable of referencing MS managed api connections, at least not that I've found so far.

Answer (score 1):

As [azender01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71530716/how-to-create-or-import-an-azure-api-connection-microsoft-web-using-terraform#comment128052226_71530716) mentioned, the [azurerm_api_connection](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_connection) terraform resource does not support all features Azure offers.

### Workaround

In the past, i've connected a Logic App with a CosmosDb account using [ARM scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template).

With Terraform, you can deploy ARM scripts with [azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/resource_group_template_deployment). This feels like a big workaround, but i did not found a better solution.

You can export ARM scripts from existing resources in the Azure Portal and use them in your terraform `azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment`.